# In RDLC expression, how to put multiple conditions?

Tags: c#, .net, report, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

In RDLC report, I have a tablix on which I have already applied one condition to make it HIDDEN/VISIBLE.

```
=IIF(First(Fields!IsSatisfactory.Value, "DataSetCNGCertificates"), true, false)
```

But now I need to apply this also,

```
=IIF(Fields!CNGStationStatus.Value = "2", true, IIF(Fields!CNGStationStatus.Value = "3", true, false))
```

but not sure how to put both together. The later one shall be the first ot be checked.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just return the answer... Ex: (x=1 or x=2 or y='test')... The answer will return true or false, so you don't need 3 nested IIF() constructs

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want the condition to check first the `CNGStationStatus` if its `2`, else, if its `3`, else, if `IsSatisfactory` is true..
Why not keeping with the nesting like:

```
=IIF(Fields!CNGStationStatus.Value = "2", true, IIF(Fields!CNGStationStatus.Value = "3", true, IIF(First(Fields!IsSatisfactory.Value, "DataSetCNGCertificates"), true, false)))
```

?

Using the `AND` operator should be used if you like to check the condition at once:

```
=IIF(Fields!CNGStationStatus.Value = "2" AND Fields!CNGStationStatus.Value = "3", true, IIF(First(Fields!IsSatisfactory.Value, "DataSetCNGCertificates"), true, false))
```

Comment: umm yeah, kind of, I actually to check the 2,3 first if that's true than it shall hide and shall never look of rthe satisfactory which shall be only checked if 2,3 are false.

Comment: I've added the option to use the `ADD` operator